# make sense to me vs make sense for me. What's the difference?

Tags: difference, syntax

Is there any reason that explains the difference between ''This makes sense to me'' and ''This makes sense for me''?

Comment: No difference in meaning. _For_ might slightly emphasize that it was **your** conclusion, but not necessarily. The reason is that _to_ is more common for percepts like that (_seems/looks/feels/sounds/appears to me_), and using _for_ is different, hence raises a question of why, and that's one possible interpretation. For those who look for such.

Answer (score 1):

In Britain we would say "makes sense to me", but I believe (and I'm willing to be corrected) Americans have a tendency to use - "makes sense for me".

Preposition use is a constant area of divergence between British and American expression.

Other similar prepositional differences in use are: "different to" (UK), "different than" (USA); "speaking to" (UK), "speaking with" (USA); "at the weekend" (UK), "on the weekend" (USA).

Comment: I (British) might use 'it makes sense to me' when I mean 'it is understandable to me' or 'I agree with what you say'- e.g. 'your explanation makes sense to me', and I could say that something (e.g. a proposed arrangement) makes sense **for** me if I mean it suits my individual circumstances ('suits me'), e.g. 'the idea of flexible working makes sense for me because I have to use public transport and might not be able to always arrive by 9 AM' or 'having the office on the ground floor makes sense for me because I am a wheelchair user'.

Comment: I (UK) was taught to say _different from_!

Comment: I am used to saying & writing in British English e.g. 'Payments are made on the 17th of each month, unless that date falls **on** a weekend, in which case the last previous working day is used'.

Comment: American here: "Makes sense *to* me" feels much more natural, and [Ngrams seems to bear that out](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sense+to+me%2Csense+for+me&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csense%20to%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csense%20for%20me%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That's with the indefinite article - "falls on a weekend" sounds quite natural to me too. But definitely not  "We're going to be busy on the weekend"

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I'd also agree about "Flexible working makes sense for me". But that's a slightly different meaning of "makes sense" - and a relatively recent one I suspect. But this probably answers the OP's question. There you have two different senses of "makes sense" and one takes "to" and the other "for".

Comment: @KateBunting Now Derby is north of a straight line drawn from the Severn to the Wash. And that is the great linguistical divide. My suspicion is that we may be into a North/  South bifurcation here.  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @WS2 - Not according to [this](https://proofed.co.uk/writing-tips/different-from-different-to-different-than/)

Comment: @WS2 - What's the relevance of Derby?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - It's my home city (mentioned in my profile).

Comment: @KateBunting I can accept "from" or "to", though the latter is what I use and will continue to do so. However I have never been able to take "than" seriously in this context. It strains the boundaries of semantics, in my view, to say "different than". "Than" is a preposition used between comparators - *John is bigger than George*. "Different than" seems to make no sense, unless you say "John and Jenny are more different (to one another) than Fred and Muriel".

Comment: @KateBunting If Derby is a city, why is the football team called Derby County? Perhaps that's a question for the Sports site.

Comment: @WS2 - I agree about _different than_, but that's the Americans for you. Derby became a city in 1977. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derby_County_F.C.), the club was originally going to be called Derbyshire County.

Comment: @KateBunting - My father's family came from a place called Castle Donington, which you may have heard of. I spent a good part of my childhood there.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Certainly I know Castle Donington - my grandmother had a friend there. Now famous for East Midlands Airport and Donington Park racetrack.

Comment: @KateBunting - my grandfather, James Harvey, was chair of the CD Rural District Council for many years and Harvey Road in CD is named after him.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Interesting. There's a Harvey Road in Derby too, but a quick search doesn't reveal the origin of the name.

Answer (score 1):

A low-carb diet might not make sense **to** someone because they don’t understand the logic of it, but a low-carb diet could make sense **for** someone because of their health goals.

Similarly, I could say a deal makes sense to me because I understand its technical details. At the same time I could say a deal doesn’t make sense for me because I’m not making money on the deal.

X “makes sense for” her/me/him/you/them because Y

X “makes sense to” her/me/him/you/them because she/I/he/you/they understand it intellectually.

Answer (score 0):

The structure is **makes sense (for somebody) to do something.** For instance,

- It doesn't make sense for me to play video games for hours.

Now, let's split it.

-Do you play video games for long hours?

-No, not at all. It (playing video games) doesn't make sense **for** me.

or

-Do you play video games for long hours?

-It doesn't make sense **to** waste time in a virtual world; I'm too old for this.

See [LDOCE](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/make-sense)

Answer (score 0):

Americans do not say "makes sense for me". Makes sense "for" me makes it seem like whatever makes sense was made sense specifically for the person saying this. I think it can be used. If something makes sense to make me happy, then it makes sense for me.